# Estimate on the derivative of a power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

The exercise is to show that if $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k z^k$ has a convergence radius $R>0$ and let $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{k!} z^k$, then there exists constant $C$ such that for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$,
$$
|f^{(n)}(z)|\leq C\frac{e^{|z|/R}}{R^n}.
$$
My work:

By checking the coefficients, I can show that $f$ is an entire function so I can diffferentiate by terms:
$
f^{(n)}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n+k}}{k!}z^k.
$
Combining with $e^{z/R}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\frac{z^k}{R^k},$
I also need $|a_{n+k}|\leq\frac{C}{R^{n+k}}$.

However, by $\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}=\frac1R$, I only have $R^n|a_n|<(1+\epsilon)^n$ for $n$ large enough, which can not be bounded by a constant.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you need a boundness condition on $g(z)=\sum a_k z^k$ on the disc of radius $R$; otherwise a simple counterexample like $a_n=n, R=1$ easily shows the result to be false as $f(z)=\sum \frac{k}{k!}z^k=ze^z$ which doesn't satisfy the required relation

Comment: @Conrad Yes! Thank you very much!